# Flutter: Material icons not showing when importing a custom Font

Tags: flutter

the original Material Icons in FLutter `Icon(Icons.access_alarms)` stop working every time I try to define a new custom font for my app.

What I do is to import the font in the `pubspec.yaml`file correctly, include the "uses-material-design:true" and define the font in main ThemeData using the fontFamily property.

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
  fonts:
    - family: Core Sans C
      fonts:
        - asset: Fonts/coresansc-45regular-webfont.ttf
          style: normal
          weight: 500
```

[screenshot of the pubspec.yaml including the font definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfpsD.png)

```
ThemeData kThemeLB = ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'Core Sans C',
    backgroundColor: kBgColor1,
    primaryColor: kMainColor,
    // primarySwatch: kMainColor,
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(
        color: kSecondaryColor,
      ),
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBgColor1);
```

And my `main.dart`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: kThemeLB,
      home: LoadLogin(),
```

My fonts DIR

[Fonts dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8yLL.png)

I can use FontAwesome Icons correctly, but still I'd like to know what the issue is.

I've been looking for a solution for a long time now but I can't seem to figure out what's the problem here. Any help is much appreciated thank!

Comment: Share your font dir please, I need to see name of the fonts and its structure

Answer (score 1):

Try move your files inside your assets dir, for example:

```
 - assets
 -- fonts
 --- **"your fonts inside fonts dir"**
```

after that modify your **pubspec file**, like this:

```
fonts:
 - family: coreSansC
 - fonts:
   - asset: assets/fonts/coresansc-45regular-webfont.ttf
```

finally modify your **ThemeData**, like this:

```
ThemeData kThemeLB = ThemeData(
    fontFamily: 'coreSansC',
    backgroundColor: kBgColor1,
    primaryColor: kMainColor,
    // primarySwatch: kMainColor,
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(
        color: kSecondaryColor,
      ),
    ),
```

I recommend you use camelCase names.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. The Core Sans C font is loading OK, the problem is that it's breaking my Material Icons.

Comment: Share the error message please, to help

Comment: Actually It works now, after a hard stop and a flutter clean, Thanks!